# IN FLASH AS3 MOBILE APP - how to make soft keyboard show only numbers or for email?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, mobile-application

I am making a mobile app with adobe air 3.9 and in the registration form, I wish to make email text-field have a keyboard or soft-keyboard type as email (i.e. having a button for ".com" and "@" in the soft-keyboard)and age to have numbers only.

I see some helps around but none gets me a clear idea.

Can anyone help me with a quick tutorial or a code snippet.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NativeText, look here for the great article:
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Answer (score 0):

[here's a tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html)

Just be aware there are two `SkinClasses` for `TextInput` and `TextArea`, `MobileSkin` and `StageSkin`. `StageSkin` can control the softkeyboard, but has scaling issues. `MobileSkin` can't control the softkeyborad, but doesn't have scaling issues. [Follow this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33729) and related issues for more info about that.